# How do I use a type switch to determine the type of a protoreflect.MessageDescriptor?

Tags: go, reflection, protocol-buffers

I am writing a protoc generation plugin using the [protogen](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.1/compiler/protogen) package.

I am looping the fields of a message and want to determine if a field is one of a few different message types.

It is possible to get the name of the message type as a string using:

```
field.Desc.Message().FullName() // mypackage.MyMessage
```

The problem with this approach is that I will need to switch against a string, which is error-prone:

```golang
switch field.Desc.Message().FullName(){
  case "mypackage.MyMessage":

  case "mypackage.MyMessage2":
}
```

Is there anyway to do this using a type assertion? I tried to create an instance of the message using [dynamicpc](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/dynamicpb), but the type assertion does not work:

```golang
mt := dynamicpb.NewMessage(field.Desc.Message())

msg, ok := mt.(*mypackage.MyMessage) // ok is false despite field.Desc.Message().FullName() returning mypackage.MyMessage
```

Comment: What is the result of `reflect.TypeOf(mt)`?

Comment: It's `*dynamicpb.Message`

Answer (score 1):

The function `dynamicpb.NewMessage` doesn't create a Golang structure `mypackage.MyMessage`. Instead it creates a data structure that marshals into the same binary form as `mypackage.MyMessage`

Have a look inside the [`Message` data structure](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/6875c3d7242d1a3db910ce8a504f124cb840c23a/types/dynamicpb/dynamic.go#L66):

```
// Operations which modify a Message are not safe for concurrent use.
type Message struct {
    typ     messageType
    known   map[protoreflect.FieldNumber]protoreflect.Value
    ext     map[protoreflect.FieldNumber]protoreflect.FieldDescriptor
    unknown protoreflect.RawFields
}
```

It is just a storage for field values along with with fields' metadata.